# How to force Nginx to verify upstream certificates against the hostnames present in upstream server block?

Tags: nginx, proxy, ssl-certificate, reverse-proxy

I am trying to implement HTTPS protocol communication at every layer of a proxying path. My proxying path is from client to load balancer (nginx) and then from nginx to the upstream server.

I am facing a problem when the request is proxied from nginx to the upstream server.

I am getting the following error in the nginx logs

```
2017/03/26 19:08:39 [error] 76753#0: *140 upstream SSL certificate does not match "8ba0c0da44ee43ea894987ab01cf4fbc" while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: 10.191.200.230, server: abc.uscom-central-1.ssenv.opcdev2.oraclecorp.com, request: "GET /a/a.html HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://10.240.81.28:8001/a/a.html", host: "abc.uscom-central-1.ssenv.opcdev2.oraclecorp.com:10003"
```

This is my configuration for the upstream server block

```
upstream 8ba0c0da44ee43ea894987ab01cf4fbc {
                            server slc01etc.us.oracle.com:8001 weight=1;
                    keepalive 100;
}

proxy_pass https://8ba0c0da44ee43ea894987ab01cf4fbc;
proxy_set_header Host $host:10003;
proxy_set_header WL-Proxy-SSL true;
proxy_set_header IS_SSL ssl;
proxy_ssl_trusted_certificate /u01/data/secure_artifacts/ssl/trusted_certs/trusted-cert.pem;
proxy_ssl_verify on;proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
```

When the request goes from Nginx to the upstream server, nginx matches the upstream ssl certificate against the pattern present in the proxy_pass directive. But my upstream ssl certificate pattern is the upstream server hostname (slc01etc.us.oracle.com) .

Is there any way, where I can force Nginx to verify the upstream ssl certificate against the server hostnames provided in the upstream server block, instead of the pattern present in the proxy_pass directibve?

Comment: Can anyone please help me with this issue?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Have you found a solution yet?

Comment: @Black-Pixel We can make use of the proxy_ssl_name directive in nginx. It allows overriding the hostname against which nginx should verify the certificate of the backend server.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can make use of the "proxy_ssl_name" directive in nginx. It allows overriding the hostname against which nginx should verify the certificate of the backend server.

```
proxy_ssl_name mybackend-server.hostname.com;
```

Comment: Question is old, but for anyone landing here now, in addition to this directive, I also needed to add the following property:
proxy_ssl_server_name on;

Comment: Is there a way to do this for multiple backends? I have several and want to be able to let them all succeed.